# Single Instance Mongodb Replica Set - cannot perform query/insert operations

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

After installing mongodb, I ran `mongod` with

```
mongod --dbpath <pathtodb> --logpath <pathtolog> --replSet rs0
```

I then connected with the mongo shell and ran

```
rs.initiate()
```

I then tried to insert a document into a collection, but received an error:

```
> db.blah.insert({a:1})
WriteResult({ "writeError" : { "code" : undefined, "errmsg" : "not master" } })
```

Looking at `rs.status()`, I see the status is `REMOVED`:

```
> rs.status()
{
        "state" : 10,
        "stateStr" : "REMOVED",
        "uptime" : 1041,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1429037007, 1),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-04-14T18:43:27Z"),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Our replica set config is invalid or we are not a member of it",
        "code" : 93
}
```

I have no idea what I could have done to mess this up. This *should* have worked I think. How do I get past this?

Comment: There is only one member of the replica set. I am trying to use it as a replica set so I can tail the oplog and see changes as they occur.

Comment: Since it's just a test setup, wipe it out and start over. Something was done to mess it up but we can't tell what, not without seeing the rs.conf(), at least.

Comment: Hrmm. that did seem to work. No clue what exactly caused the problem. Works now...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem here is that you ran `rs.initiate()`.. As EMPTY!  You didn't tell what machines belongs to that replica set.

So..

```
rs.initiate({
      _id: "rs0",
      version: 1,
      members: [
         { _id: 0, host : "address.to.this.machine:27017" }
      ]
   }
)
```

Comment: Empty `rs.initiate()` is fine, you just need to follow that with e.g.  `rs.add("db.example.com")`

Answer (score 11):

As above answers said, the config is not set correctly.

I tried to re-init the replica, but got the error msg:

```
singleNodeRepl:OTHER> rs.initiate({ _id: "rs0", members: [ { _id: 0, host : "localhost:27017" } ] } )
{
    "info" : "try querying local.system.replset to see current configuration",
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "already initialized",
    "code" : 23,
    "codeName" : "AlreadyInitialized"
}
```

The solution is to `reconf` the mongo:

```
singleNodeRepl:OTHER> rsconf = rs.conf()
singleNodeRepl:OTHER> rsconf.members = [{_id: 0, host: "localhost:27017"}]
[ { "_id" : 0, "host" : "localhost:27017" } ]
singleNodeRepl:OTHER> rs.reconfig(rsconf, {force: true})
{ "ok" : 1 }
singleNodeRepl:OTHER>
singleNodeRepl:SECONDARY>
singleNodeRepl:PRIMARY>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Ran into the exact same problem.  Should be good now when container is restarted/updated since using localhost.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:**

I needed to do:

```
rs.initiate({_id:'rs0', version: 1, members: [{_id: 0, host:'localhost:27017'}]}
```

rather than `rs.initiate()`.

**Long Answer:**

I am almost the same as @Madbreaks and @Yihe 's comment, but I was in the different background so that I'm adding my comment here.

*Background*

I used docker container of mongoDB and initiated the replicaset by `rs.initiate()`. (The data volume is mounted to the host, but it is out-of-topic here).

*What Happend*

When I restart the mongoDB container, the error "MongoError: not master and slaveOk=false" happened.  Yes, the error message was different from @d0c_s4vage 's, but the workaround is the same as @Yihe 's.

*Root Cause*

The root cause was dynamically assigned hostname as follows:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "rs0",
    ...
    "members" : [
        {
            ...
            "host" : "ee4ed99b555e:27017",  # <----- !!!!
```

Where, the host "ee4..." above comes from docker container's internal hostname; this is set by my first `rs.initiate()`.  This would be changed when recreate container.  In my case, localhost is fine because of single server and single replicaset for 'rocketchat' app evaluation purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing same issue, I tried below steps,

**NOTE:** If you have already cluster setup follow my steps

- I stopped particular server (host : "address.to.this.machine:27017")
- Remove **mongod.lock** file
- create one more data directory 
         - (deafult: /data/db,  new Data directory: /data/db_rs0)
- update the **configuration ** file 
        -change dbpath ( "/data/db_rs0" ),
        - check bindIP (default: 127.0.0.0 to 0.0.0.0)
- Check Hostname & Hosts

  > **hostname**
  >
  > **sudo vi /etc/hosts**

add to hosts

```
         127.0.0.0 hostname

         127.0.1.1 hostname

        (add your Public/Private IP)   hostname
```

- Start the MONGODB server in

  **sudo /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf &**

> rs.initiate({ _id: "rs0", members: [ { _id: 0, host : "hostname:27017" } ] } )
>
> rs.status()

{

....

"members": [

```
{

  "_id": 0,

  "name": "hostname:27017",

  "health": 1,

  "state": 1,

  "stateStr": "PRIMARY",

  "uptime": 98231,

  "optime": {

    "ts": Timestamp(1474963880, 46),

    "t": NumberLong(339)
  },

  "optimeDate": ISODate("2016-09-27T08:11:20Z"),

  "electionTime": Timestamp(1474956813, 1),

  "electionDate": ISODate("2016-09-27T06:13:33Z"),

  "configVersion": 12,

  "self": true
},
```

...........

]

"ok": 1

}

-------- THANK YOU --------

Comment: Local host address is 127.0.0.1 and not 127.0.0.0. You are talking about cluster, when you really mean replica set... ;-)